# StackNavigator can not be accessed from DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am creating a story app with two sections Love Stories and Jokes,
I am serving this two sections using Drawer Navigator. When a user enters Love stories or jokes using drawer navigator, they can see a list of love stories or jokes based on the selection. Upon clicking on a certain item, it shows the detail of either a love story or a joke. The drawer navigation successfully works but when I try to enter a detail of a list item, it shows me the error given below:

```
Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.prop.navigation.navigate)
```

**PostList.js:**

```
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Header
      headerText = {this.props.headerText}
    />
    <ScrollView>
      {this.renderPosts()}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
 );
}

renderPosts() {
  return this.state.posts.map(p=>(
    <View key={p.id}>
      <Card>
        <Button
          title="Go to Jane's profile"
          onPress={() =>
            {this.props.navigation.navigate('PostDetail')}  //error is generated here
          }
        />
      </Card>
    </View>
    )         
  )
 }       
}
```

**App.js:**

```
export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator (
  {
 LoveStory: {
   screen: (props)=> <PostList 
                       headerText = 'Love Story'
                       blogId = '5278762286036727816'
                       apiKey = 'AIghSyDzawc245f4_sgIv8lSucdp7yJs__O29Qw'
                     />,
   navigationOptions: {
       drawerLabel: 'Love Story',
   },
 },
 Jokes: {
    screen: (props)=> <PostList 
                       headerText = 'Jokes'
                       blogId = '3124493334962174072'
                       apiKey = 'AIbJXRBgxJZvBQzaSyJAyq4_irQ-2OCOkFyrpH8'
                     />,
   navigationOptions: {
       drawerLabel: 'Jokes',
   },
 },},{
initialRouteName: 'LoveStory',
drawerPosition: 'left',
});

export const StackNav = StackNavigator(
{
  Main: {
    screen: Drawer
  },
  PostDetail: {
    screen: PostDetail,
  }
  },{
    headerMode: 'none'
  });
```

**index.js:**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import {StackNav} from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('golpo_app', () => StackNav);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass the `navigation` prop down to your `PostList` component.

To fix that, change this in App.js:

```
   screen: (props)=> <PostList 
                       headerText = 'Love Story'
                       blogId = '5278762286036727816'
                       apiKey = 'AIghSyDzawc245f4_sgIv8lSucdp7yJs__O29Qw'
                     />,
```

to

```
   screen: (props)=> <PostList 
                       headerText = 'Love Story'
                       blogId = '5278762286036727816'
                       apiKey = 'AIghSyDzawc245f4_sgIv8lSucdp7yJs__O29Qw'
                       {...props}
                     />,
```

or

```
   screen: (props)=> <PostList 
                       headerText = 'Love Story'
                       blogId = '5278762286036727816'
                       apiKey = 'AIghSyDzawc245f4_sgIv8lSucdp7yJs__O29Qw'
                       navigation = {props.navigation}
                     />,
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you so much. It solved the problem like a charm!